# Always show vertical scrollbar

Tags: feature-request

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask fits on my screen entirely without a scrollbar, with a tiny amount of space left.

When using a browser that only show a vertical scrollbar when necessary, this causes a lot of jumping while typing the question's title. There's a very fast cycle between *That title is too short to be useful. Can you add some more detail?* and the animation that appears while loading similar questions, so the vertical scrollbar will appear and disappear equally fast.

Something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/4050094/247702 would make this problem go away.

```
body { overflow-y:scroll; }
```

Comment: So the scroll bar appears and disappears as required. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: It appears and disappears at a rate of 5 times per second, so the website content is shifted and unshifted very fast.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. When I resize my browser to not show a scrollbar, then the scrollbar shows up as soon as some message shows up. But there's no flashing or appearing/disappearing. Which browser do you use? I use Chrome.

Comment: I'm using Firefox. Screenshot of the situation: http://i.imgur.com/3epC5G9.png For me the scrollbar shows up when the loading animation is visible, but it disappears when it decides that my question title is not yet long enough. So every time I type a letter, the scrollbar appear/disappear cycle repeats itself.

Comment: I'm not really seeing the problem you are discribing, not unless I just misunderstand your issue altogether.

Comment: I'll try to make a video of this today.